# Svelte does not update the components when values change

Tags: javascript, svelte-3, sveltekit

I have used Vue.js extensively in the past so this pattern may not translate well to svelte, I understand that.

My question is why doesn't the following work in svelte and what is the correct pattern to use.

When I click on the edit button, It works as expected, but when I click save it doesn't revert back to main component. The values seem to be updated but the component doesn't refresh.

## Main.svelte

```
<script>
        import Editing from './editing.svelte';
        let data = true;
    let editing = false;
    let editingSection;

    function startEditing(section) {
        editingSection = section;
        editing = true;
    }

    function doneEditing() {
        editing = false;
        editingSection = '';
    }

</script>

<div>
    {#if data && !editing}
        <div>
                  Yes we have data!
        <button on:click={startEditing("main")}>Edit</button>
        </div>
    {/if}

    <!-- Are we in editing mode -->
    {#if editing}
        <Editing section={editingSection} on:done-editing={doneEditing}/>
    {/if}
</div>
```

## editing.svelte

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    export let section = null;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function save() {
        dispatch('done-editing');
    }

</script>

<div>
    Editing Section {section}
    <button on:click={save}>Save</button>
</div>
```

*I have even tried the $: to make the statements reactive. Doesn't work*

*Svelte Version: 3.34.0*

*SvelteKit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that `<button on:click={startEditing('main')}>` does not do what you expect it to do.  It will during render *execute* the `startEditing` function and add the *return value* of this function as a listener to the click event.

The correct syntax would be: `<button on:click={() => startEditing('main')}>` as you see here, the handler is a *function*.

In the other event handler: `<Editing on:done-editig={doneEditing}>` you are correctly passing a function.

Comment: Wow, that worked! I didn't know about the handler behaviour. I thought it was just the function name we have to pass. Thanks for your help.